# Child element by class name error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to access the element with class ="hs-input" ; this is the basic structure

```
<div class = "hbspt-form".......>
 <form ....class="hs-form stacked">
      <div class = "hs_firstname field hs-form-field"...>
          <div class = "input"....>
              <div class="hs-input"...>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("hbspt-form")[0];
list.style.background = "#fffbd5";
list.style.borderRadius = "5px";
list.style.border= "solid";
list.style.boxShadow = "10px 20px 30px ";
list.style.borderColor = "#f7761f";
list.getElementsByClassName("hs_firstname")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
</script>
```

I am unable to even access the second class(hs-form stacked), Could anyone tell me how to change the background colour of the last class(hs-input)

Note: The console doesn't give any errors if I enter any of the functions but when I execute this it says that the code is not found.

I am new to javascript and stack overflow, please help with patience.Thanks

**Note: This is the code-> http://jsfiddle.net/jg2rek1h/**

Comment: could you include full html, css, and javascript code?

Comment: @Urahara Hi they are very big files,should i still include them.What is unclear with the code that I have written? I can provide more information if  you need any

Comment: @dandavis I am sorry I can made the change it was a typo.

Comment: @MaxZoom This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/jg2rek1h/

Comment: @Urahara Hey I have added my code please take a look.Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted is a mess.. Split javascript to the javascript part of the window. **Anyway are you aware that you can use it like that `document.getElementsByClassName("hs-form stacked");` ?**

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, it didn't work. Can you figure out why?

Comment: **PLEASE for the love of god, write what you are tiring to accomplish?**
- do you want to change the visual outlook only?
- do you want to manipulate all elements that inherit specific `class`
- do you want to get your hands only on the one element ex. `last` or `third` of the form that uses specific `class` ?

**EDIT YOUR POST TO BE SPECIFIC**

Comment: @Urahara I have made it clear in the question, I am trying to change the last class(hs-input)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("hbspt-form")[0];

var secondclass = list.getElementsByClassName('hs-form')[0];
secondclass.style.background = "#333";

var last_class = list.getElementsByClassName('hs-input')[0];
last_class.style.color = "#94d";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k581sL5q/

Comment: No, it didn't work. it is giving me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'second_class.style'). thanks for trying though. Do you know what the issue is? also do checkout the jsfiddle in the question

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't define `var` that is why you got that error, I just fixed that.

Comment: [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'second_class.style')
 global code (freetrial.html, line 248)

Comment: Yes, I found that too, I tried in fiddle and now it is fine, You must check it now. .:)

Answer (score 0):

I just added the **css** sheet, check this : http://jsfiddle.net/jg2rek1h/4/

If you just want to change the visual outlook use `css` http://www.w3schools.com/css/

If you want to manipulate the look by script, better get along with jQuery for that matter.